# Поиск схожих функций в разных языках

Tags: php, c++, функции

В PHP есть функция links. Есть ли схожая функция на C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложно понять вопрос. Если имеется в виду функция [link](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.link.php), которая создает жесткую ссылку на файл, то в Unix/Linux есть такая же функция для C/++. Описание можно посмотреть командой `man 2 link`.

Применительно к Windows и NTFS похожая вещь, вроде, называется [точки соединения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_NTFS). Наверное, в WinAPI есть средства, чтобы создавать их из C/++